# how can i sum two columns of two tables in a main form in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following:
=Nz(Sum("[Column]","[Table-1]")0,) This worked alright for one of the tables, but i need the two tables calculated, and this is what i have for the two tables,
=Nz(Sum("[Column]","[Table-1]" & And (Sum("[Column]","[Table-2]")0,) This is not working, error message #Name#

Please help me.

Comment: your going to have to provide more information for a specific answer.  Make a minimal reproducible example.    so show what you have (with data we can copy and show what you want.   I can't tell at this point whether you need a calculated field in a query or a total row on a form.  review calculated field and dlookup for the query and running total for the form.

Comment: I don't see how any of posted expressions could work. Perhaps should be DSum(), not Sum().

Comment: the error message #Name# means that there is no such function Sum() post your actual code!

Comment: Welcome Layi! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: The `DSUM` function https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dsum-function-08f8450e-3bf6-45e2-936f-386056e61a32

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
=Nz(DSum("[Column]","[Table-1]"),0)+Nz(DSum("[Column]","[Table-2]"),0)
```